# LM386 driving transformer going into oscillation

Tags: amplifier, audio, lm386

I have a transformer on the output of a LM386. The circuit works just fine with 42TU003-RC, but when I use any other transformer the circuit goes into osillation at ~350 kHz on the output of the LM386.

NOTE: Since it's not pictured, the rail voltage of pin 6 of the LM386 input is ~12-14.5 V from a car battery and is on the left side of Q5.

My initial thoughts of what may be the issue is that the new transformer's impedance is much higher (which I'm in the process of measuring) and that I need to adjust the C20 and R21 values of the Zobel circuit to help maintain stability.

Maybe changing the value of C20 to 1 μF and keep R21 to 10 Ω setting the cutoff frequency to ~16 kHz. The only problem with this is loading the LM386 at anything above 16 kHz.

This is an audio application so there shouldn't be too much above 16 kHz.

Is there anything else I should check or consider?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you are deriving the C20 and R21 values for the Zobel network? Given some back-of-the-napkin maths I suspect your calculations might be off, and you might just be getting away with it on the smaller transformer.

Comment: Data sheet links to all relevant parts please. A full circuit, not a partial circuit please. "*Since it's not pictured*" <-- picture it in the schematic please. Explain the inductor on the LM386 output please. What does the output connect to i.e. what are those transistors on the output doing?

Comment: Just a note, many op-amps will oscillate when driving "a capacitance", which you partially have here.  Suggest [researching this topic](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=op+amp+output+capacitance+oscillating) for more info.